# Print name of all activities with neither maximum nor minimum number of participants

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i solve this question of hackerrank. I am quite confused an unable to move forward with this. 
[image]
[image]

here is what i have tried

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ACTIVITY FROM FRIENDS,
 SELECT max(ACTIVITY) AS M
 WHERE M = (SELECT NAME FROM Activities);
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images). And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh edited already

Comment: That's neither sample data nor expected result. And images...

Comment: @jarlh sorry check now

Comment: Checked.... :-(

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry i have added everything now. can you move forward with the details i have provided till now? I really need this solution

Comment: I would have expected friends.activity to be an int orherwise activities is a pointless table

Comment: but still i can't change the question now though. any solution for this problem @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window functions` if your mysql version is 8 or above

```
select activity from (select activity, count(*) as cnt,
                             max(count(*)) over () as maximum_cnt,
                             min(count(*)) over () as minimum_cnt
                        from friends group by activity) mytable
where cnt not in (maximum_cnt, minimum_cnt);
```

Comment: 'You can use window functions' - maybe, if on version 8 or above

Comment: @P.Salmon. Thanks for pointing out. I have added the note in the answer

Comment: what do i need to write in place of mytable? @ArunPalanisamy

Comment: @ahsannissar, That is just an alias. You can write anything

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using mysql

```
select activity 
from 
(select activity, count(activity) as cnt
from friends
group by activity 
having cnt <> (select count(activity) from friends group by activity order by count(activity) limit 1)
and
cnt <> (select count(activity) from friends group by activity order by count(activity) desc limit 1)
) as x;
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to solve tasks like this with left join and checking NULL:

```
SELECT 
    ACTIVITY,
    SUM(1) AS Total
INTO #ActivityCount 
FROM FRIENDS
GROUP BY ACTIVITY

SELECT
    ActivityCount.ACTIVITY
FROM #ActivityCount
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(ActivityCount.Total) AS Total FROM ActivityCount) AS MaxTotal
    ON ActivityCount.Total = MaxTotal.Total
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(ActivityCount.Total) AS Total FROM ActivityCount) AS MinTotal
    ON ActivityCount.Total = MinTotal.Total
WHERE
    MaxTotal.Total IS NULL
    AND MinTotal.Total IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what i did

```
Select ACTIVITY from Friends 
group by ACTIVITY
having count(ACTIVITY) <> (select count1 from (select count(ACTIVITY) 
    count1 from Friends 
    group by (ACTIVITY) 
    order by count1 asc) 
    where rownum <= 1) and count(ACTIVITY) <> (select count2 from (select count(ACTIVITY) count2 from Friends group by (ACTIVITY) order by count2 desc) where rownum <= 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with temp as
(
select activity, count(id) as act_count from friends
group by activity
)

select activity from temp
where act_count not in (select max(act_count) from temp)
and act_count not in (select min(act_count) from temp);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some extra explanation while formatting the SQL statement by using Ctrl+K or restricting within [triple bacticks]+sql   ..- .->   [triple bacticks]   delimiters.