# What is the correct solution for the below SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, greatest-n-per-group

[Print name of all activities with neither maximum nor minimum number of participants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642383/print-name-of-all-activities-with-neither-maximum-nor-minimum-number-of-particip)

I have tried the below query but is giving me error:

```
select ACTIVITY
from (select ACTIVITY, count(*) as cnt,
             max(count(*)) as max_cnt,
             min(count(*)) as min_cnt
      from FRIENDS GROUP BY ACTIVITY) FRIENDS
where cnt not in (max_cnt, min_cnt);
```

> ERROR: ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 1: Invalid use of group function
>   MYSQL VERSION: 8

Comment: Version 14? I'm seriously out of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you are not running MySQL 8.0 (otherwise the answer given on your previous question would have just worked).

In earlier versions, you can do:

```
select activity, count(*) no_activities
from friends
group by activity
having 
        count(*) > (select count(*) from friends group by activity order by count(*)  asc limit 1)
    and count(*) < (select count(*) from friends group by activity order by count(*) desc limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want window functions:

```
select ACTIVITY
from (select ACTIVITY, count(*) as cnt,
             max(count(*)) over () as max_cnt,
             min(count(*)) over () as min_cnt
      from FRIENDS 
      group by activity
     ) a
where cnt not in (max_cnt, min_cnt);
```

The above requires MySQL 8+.  In earlier version, it is more painful:

```
select a.ACTIVITY
from (select ACTIVITY, count(*) as cnt,
             max(count(*)) over () as max_cnt,
             min(count(*)) over () as min_cnt
      from FRIENDS 
      group by activity
     ) a join
     (select min(cnt) as min_cnt, max(cnt) as max_cnt
      from (select activity, count(*) as cnt
            from friends
            group by activity
           ) a
     ) am
     on a.cnt not in (am.max_cnt, am.min_cnt);
```

Comment: still it gives at error at line 3 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() as max_cnt,
             min(count(*)) over () as min_cnt
      from FRIENDS ' at line 3

Comment: any other way to do this apart from window function in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it should work using window function in `MySQL 8.0`.

```
select
    activity
from
(
    select 
        activity, 
        count(*) over () as ttl,
        dense_rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
    from friends 
    group by 
        activity
)  val
where rnk != 1 and rnk != ttl - 1
```

Comment: this is also giving error:
ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 1: Invalid use of group function

Comment: @NirajSingh which `MySQL` version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 8

Comment: @NirajSingh I have added another solution using window function, which can also be used to solve your problem.